# Failed to create JS object from HTML form data

Tags: javascript

In the following code I'm trying to create a human object from form data. The `userData` object returns undefined for all values but I am assigning values in the function that retrieves the data. If I console.log the `userData` object I see '{}' then when expanding I see the values but after creating the human object those same values show undefined. How can I assign those `values` to the human object so it keeps those values? Thank you.

```
function Human(name, height, weight, diet) {
    this.name = name;
    this.height = height;
    this.weight = weight;
    this.diet = diet;
}
    
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
const userData = {};
function getUserData() {
    let formContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('form-container')[0];

    formContainer.style.display = 'none';
    let main = document.getElementById('grid');
    main.style.display = 'flex';

    let name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    let feet = parseFloat(document.getElementById('feet').value);
    let inches = parseFloat(document.getElementById('inches').value);
    let height = (feet * 12) + inches;
    let weight = parseFloat(document.getElementById('weight').value);
    let diet = document.getElementById('diet').value;

    userData.name = name;
    userData.height = height;
    userData.weight = weight;
    userData.diet = diet;

}

console.log(userData);
// Create Human Object
const human = new Human(userData.name, userData.height, userData.weight, userData.display);
console.log(human);
```

Comment: firstly your problem is not clear. At least, I couldn't really understand. Secondly, is `getUserData` function ever called in somewhere before you print `userData`

Comment: Yes. I updated the post. I am calling the getUserData on button click and trying to create object from the retrieved data.

Comment: @larry8989 have you seen my answer below. Its exactly working as you wanted in your form with a button click - Let me know

Answer (score 2):

I think you might want to refactor to this instead so that the function `getUserData()` is more reusable.

```
function getUserData() {

    let formContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('form-container')[0];
    formContainer.style.display = 'none';

    let main = document.getElementById('grid');
    main.style.display = 'flex';

    const name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    const feet = parseFloat(document.getElementById('feet').value);
    const inches = parseFloat(document.getElementById('inches').value);
    const height = (feet * 12) + inches;
    const weight = parseFloat(document.getElementById('weight').value);
    const diet = document.getElementById('diet').value;

    return {name, height, weight, diet}
}

const userData = getUserData()
const human = new Human(userData.name, userData.height, userData.weight, userData.diet);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript [class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) and a [constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/constructor) method to store your userData `data`. So that you can use access your data via new `Human` class.

Ideally in modern `JS` you want to `class` function instead of `simple` as this be re-useable as well as the simple one but its a **good** practice to use a class function since that's what you are trying to do as well.

**Live Working Demo:**

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
let userData = {};

class Human {
  constructor(name, height, weight, diet) {
    this.name = name;
    this.height = height;
    this.weight = weight;
    this.diet = diet;
  }
}

function getUserData() {
  let name = document.getElementById('name').value;
  let feet = parseFloat(document.getElementById('feet').value);
  let inches = parseFloat(document.getElementById('inches').value);
  let height = (feet * 12) + inches;
  let weight = parseFloat(document.getElementById('weight').value);
  let diet = document.getElementById('diet').value;

  //Store to object
  userData.name = name;
  userData.height = height;
  userData.weight = weight;
  userData.diet = diet;
}

// call getUserData on button click
btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()

  getUserData() //call function on click

  // Create Human Object
  const human = new Human(userData.name, userData.height, userData.weight, userData.diet);
  console.log(human); //create object

});
```

```html
<form id="dino-compare">
  <div class="form-container">
    <p>Name:</p>
    <input id="name" class="form-field__full" type="name" name="name">
    <p>Height</p>
    <label>Feet: <input id="feet" class="form-field__short" type="number" name="feet"></label>
    <label>inches: <input id="inches" class="form-field__short" type="number" name="inches"></label>
    <p>Weight:</p>
    <label><input id="weight" class="form-field__full" type="number" name="weight">lbs</label>
    <p>Diet:</p>
    <select id="diet" class="form-field__full" name="diet">
      <option>Herbavor</option>
      <option>Omnivor</option>
      <option>Carnivor</option>
    </select>
    <button id="btn" onclick="getUserData(event)">Compare Me!</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, any function (except for `=>` functions) can be used as a constructor, just by using the `new` keyword when calling it.  The class declaration is unnecessary in this case, but it is a good idea to use it in modern JS.

Comment: *but it is a good idea to use it in modern JS* => thats why i added the class function instead of simple one.

Comment: Right. It's best practice. But if you read an older tutorial before the class keyword was introduced, you would see the style the OP used.  I think it's important to explain that both styles are correct, to prevent confusion, and explain when to use one vs. the other

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jQuery `serializaArray()` method

```
  function Human(name, height, weight, diet) {
      this.name = name;
      this.height = height;
      this.weight = weight;
      this.diet = diet;
  }

  (function ($) {
      $.fn.serializeFormJSON = function () {

          var o = new Human();
          var a = this.serializeArray();
          $.each(a, function () {
              if (o[this.name]) {
                  if (!o[this.name].push) {
                      o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
                  }
                  o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
              } else {
                  o[this.name] = this.value || '';
              }
          });
          return o;
      };
  })(jQuery);

  $('form').submit(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var data = $(this).serializeFormJSON();
      console.log(data);
  });
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mL32gvd0/1/

Answer (score 0):

because you never call getUserData function

it may look like following:

```js
getUserData();
console.log(userData);
const human = new Human(userData.name, userData.height, userData.weight, userData.display);
console.log(human);
```